# Mouse automatically reverts back to center of my dual display when I navigate from one monitor to another in my remote machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitor setup, I didn't face this issue before one week, it was working perfectly. This doesn't happen in my local machine, this happens only when I take remote desktop of my office machine. Check the below gif. This is really making my wfh life hell. How to fix this ?

OS : Windows 10

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what OS and video configuration you have in your remote machine and your local machine.
Can you identify any possible change that relates to the issue?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio which video configuration ?

Comment: Configuration -> System -> Display

Comment: Did you try any of what was suggested? Please post feedback of whatever you could test. This is an essential way to help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a complex and very much ill-defined issue, I will give a few option to try, and questions for more info.
Consider combinations of the points below, when applicable.

1. Check which mouse/touchpad drivers you have. Do you have more than one?
   Try keeping only one by disabling others. Try reinstalling the driver.
2. If you have a touch screen, disable it. If that is the problem, clean it to see if it fixes the problem.
3. Settings -> Mouse -> Pointer Options -> Enhance pointer precision -> Uncheck.
4. Do you have Steam installed? Try uninstalling.
5. Start without the mouse, use only the touchpad.
6. Connect from another PC.
7. Edit the Mouse Properties to disable pointer shadow. https://interworks.com/blog/smatlock/2014/12/29/fixing-jumpy-mouse-windows-server-2012-r2-remote-desktop.
8. How is the communication with your Remote Desktop?
   Bandwidth issues may have an impact, e.g.
   If you have another PC at home, try RDP with that PC to see what happens. https://serverfault.com/questions/515809/mouse-cursor-jumps-around-when-using-rdp
9. Check the options of the Remote Desktop client. Some may help reducing bandwidth usage, as video resolution, color depth, etc.
10. Force XDDM driver use.
    Which Windows 10 version do you have?
    https://borncity.com/win/2019/10/30/windows-10-v1903-mouse-stutter-with-rdp-sessions/

Possibly Related:

https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/jumping-cursor-in-windows-10/

https://windowsreport.com/cursor-freezes-jumps-disappears-windows-8-10/

https://forum.devolutions.net/topics/27906/rightclick-in-rdp-session--mouse-cursur-jumps

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/remote-desktop-connection-cursor-moves-all-over/1e8543a8-3475-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226082/device-misdetected-as-serial-mouse

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/819036/overview-of-the-comdisable-tool